# Prove $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 x^n \sin x \,dx = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Prove $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 x^n \sin x \,dx = 0$.

Since for $x \in[0,1]$, $x^n \geq 0$ and $0 \leq \sin x \leq 1$, we have $$0 \leq \int_0^1 x^n \sin x \,dx \leq \int_0^1 x^n \,dx = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\Bigm|_0^1$$
which goes to zero as $n \to \infty$.

This proof seems almost trivial, which is surprising since the question comes from [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-100a-real-analysis-fall-2020/mit18_100af20_hw_final.pdf).  Is it correct?

Comment: Yep that's correct, nicely done. Perhaps the question was intended to catch students carelessly interchanging limit and integral without justification (for example, the sequence of functions given by $f_n(x)=x^n\sin(x)$ does not converge uniformly on $[0,1]$)?

Comment: Why not write $\frac{1}{n+1}$ and even recall that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}, \int_0^1 x^n \sin x \,dx$ is simply a real number. The more trivial the question, the less open to criticism you should be, right?

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen I do not understand your comment.  Can you clarify?

Comment: Well, here it's not a problem; but in the context of an exam, especially on an easy question, I think it is better to write $\frac{1}{n+1}$ and not just $\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\Bigm|_0^1$. And more generally, to be as explicit as possible.

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen Thanks.  What do you mean by $\int_0^1x^n \sin x \,dx$ being "simply a real number": the integral is clearly real, but we need to show it is _zero_.

Comment: I think it would be well seen, even at MIT, to recall that we are trying to show here that a sequence of *real numbers *converges to $0$, however complicated in appearance the expression of each term of the real sequence may be. But maybe I'm too picky. :)

Comment: It's not MIT, it's MIT's open course. And I wouldn't fret about a student omitting that middle step if I was grading, but chacun a son goût.

Comment: Yes, it is a good way to do it, I suppose it was just a first step question before the next question ...